# How to add a list of strings to a new column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a string array, a = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo2'], how would you add this as a new column to an existing dataframe, df.

```
The shape of the df before adding:
  a b
0 3 3
1 3 3
2 3 3

after adding:
  a b new_column
0 3 3 foo
1 3 3 bar 
2 3 3 foo2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it in.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
>>> df["c"] = ["foo", "bar", "foo2"]
>>> df
   a  b     c
0  1  4   foo
1  2  5   bar
2  3  6  foo2
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. What if the list is not the same size as the dataframe column?  I get a, "Length of values does not match length of index" error. How would you add sequentially what you have until you run out to prevent this error?

Comment: Is the list shorter or longer than the dataframe? If it's shorter, you'd have to figure out what to pad it with (e.g. nones? empty strings?). If it's longer, and you're okay with discarding the rest, you could just slice it before assignment.

Comment: Okay, I will match the lengths then, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to worry about padding if you do it this way:

```
idx = 0
for thing in mylist:
    df.at[idx,'column_name'] = thing
    idx+=1
```